# How to get pixel neighbors in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I need to get pixel neighbors in order to get a sequence of boundary points , so my plan is to :-

1. Find a boundary pixel .
2. Find its neighbor ( it should be a boundary pixel too ) .
3. Recursively do this until i reach the starting pixel .

How can i get  pixel neighbors in MATLAB ?

Comment: Define "pixel neighbour".  Do you just mean the coordinates of pixels adjacent to the one you're considering?

Comment: yea , this is what i mean , actually i need them to use in Fourier descriptors !

Comment: Then I don't understand the problem.  The coordinates of your neighbours are `(i+1,j)`, `(i,j+1)`, `(i-1,j)`, `(i,j-1)`, along with logic to handle boundary cases.

Comment: I need 8-connectivity , providing that your way will be so expensive , isn't it ?

Answer (score 7):

You could always define a displacement vector

```
d = [ 1 0; -1 0; 1 1; 0 1; -1 1; 1 -1; 0 -1; -1 -1];
```

Then the neighbors of location `loc =[i j]` are

```
neighbors = d+repmat(loc,[8 1]);
```

Hope is useful to you...